# Javascript Assigning a keyboard shortcut to execute a function, my code isn't working, why?

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

Link to my pen: https://codepen.io/dev999/pen/pPdOGW Link to my to do app. I'm a beginner, this is my first time using a library and basic DOM manipulation.
I'd like to assign keyboard shortcuts to each action in my to do list.
Could someone please help me out with this? Thank you!

Stuff I used:

Link to Mousetrap library: cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mousetrap/1.6.1/mousetrap.js

Link to the explanations  for the library: https://craig.is/killing/mice

// Trying to assign the keyboard //shortcut ctrl+q to the action          //"addTodo()".
//Using Mousetrap library

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+q', function(e) {
 addTodo;
});
function addTodo () {
 todo.push(prompt ("Enter one item you want to add to your todo!"));
 dispTodo ();
```

}

Comment: You're not calling the function in your event handler.

Comment: Alternatively, use `Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+q', addTodo);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure where I should call the function. You mean function(e) or something else? I know how to call a function but I'm still a beginner and I don't know what to do with the Mousetrap one.

Comment: Yes, `function(e){ addTodo(); }` - just what you tried but forgot the parenthesis. Or pass `addTodo` directly.